# What is the meaning of three-headed Bhairav idols and Shiva Purana 3.8.2?

Tags: shiva, tantra, shiva-purana, idols, bhairava

[Shiva Purana 3.8.2 states](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226404.html):

> Bhairava is **the prior form of Siva**, the great soul. Fools who are deluded by Śiva’s Māyā do not know about it.
> Bhairavaḥ **pūrṇarūpo** hi śaṃkarasya parātmanaḥ | mūḍhāstaṃ vai na jānanti mohitāśśivamāyayā

Does this mean Bhairav is the primal/real/actual/original form of Shiva? Is the original form of Sadashiva (supreme god) also 3 headed Bhairav?

Answer (score 1):

No, Bhagwan Bhairava is not the prior form of Bhagwan Shiva.

The word **pūrṇarūpo** means **complete form** not  prior form. And here it is said that Lord Bhairava is the complete raudra form of Lord Shankara (viz NilaLohita/Rudra not Lord Shiva).

Shiva Maha Purana 3.8.:

> Nandīśvara said:
> 44. O sage, on hearing the haughty words of the lotus-born Brahmā, Śiva became angry as if out for destruction.
>
> 45. Angrily, **he created a Puruṣa Bhairava blazing in great brilliance.** Then he spoke lovingly.
>
> Śiva said:—
> 4-6. O Kālabhairava, at the outset this lotus-born Brahmā shall be chastised by you. You shine like god of death, hence you are Kālarāja.
>
> 47. You are called Bhairava because you are of terrifying features and you are capable of supporting the universe. Since even Kāla is afraid of you, you are called Kālabhairava.
> 48. When you arc angry you will be suppressing the wicked souls. Hence you will be known everywhere as the suppressor of the wicked.
> 49. Since you will be devouring the sins of devotees in a trice your name will be famous as sin-eater.
> 50. O Kālarāja, you will have forever the suzerainty over my city Kāśī, the city of liberation, which is greater than all other cities.
> 51. You alone will be the chastiser of those who commit sins there. Citragupta will write down their auspicious and inauspicious activities.

I hope this clarifies your queries.